# Error validación if, python

Tags: python

nosé si alguno me pueda ayudar con algo raro que me sucede, resulta que estoy haciendo una operacion matemática simple, y luego estoy validando su resultado, si dicho resultado es menor que 1 quiero imprimir en pantalla, de lo contrario no haría nada; pero al ejecutar observo que al imprimir el resultado (coberturaCuota ) y su valor es númerico sin problemas, pero al pasarlo por el condicional me lo toma como cero, lo cual me causa error lógico y no entiendo porque le asigna ese valor y termina el if como si fuese menor a 1, lo cual no deberia suceder si el valor de coberturaCuota es mayor a 0

```
    for row in pcorte:
        if row[4] == 1009:
            x = row[0]
            for row2 in aval: #consulta CPA
                if x == row2[0]:
                    baseAd115.append(itemgetter(0,1,4,6,19)(row) + itemgetter(0,1,2,3,4,6)(row2))         
    for row in baseAd115:

        if row[10] in empleados:
            cuotaCobertura = int(0)
            ingresos = row[6]
            gastos = row[7]
            cuota = row[4]
            coberturaCuota = ((ingresos - gastos) // cuota)  #Empleados: (Ingresos - gastos) / cuota
            print(row[0],"Valor variable coberturaCuota antes del if ",coberturaCuota)
            if coberturaCuota < 1:
                print(row[0],"Valor variable coberturaCuota despues del if  ",cuotaCobertura)
                res1 = (row[0],row[1],observ,accion)
                res.append(res1)
                
        if row[10] in independientes:
            cuotaCobertura = int(0)
            utilNeta = row[8]
            ingresos = row[6]
            gastos = row[7]
            cuota = row[4]            
            coberturaCuota = (((ingresos + utilNeta) - gastos)//cuota)  #Independientes: (utilidad_neta - gastos) / cuota
            print(row[0],"Valor variable coberturaCuota antes del if ",coberturaCuota)
            if cuotaCobertura < 1:
                print(row[0],"Valor variable coberturaCuota despues del if  ",cuotaCobertura)
                res1 = (row[0],row[1],observ,accion)
                res.append(res1)

    return(Base_adherencia(res))
```

```
220002393896 Valor variable coberturaCuota antes del if  5.0
220006718729 Valor variable coberturaCuota antes del if  3.0
220006718729 Valor variable coberturaCuota despues del if   0
220006718750 Valor variable coberturaCuota antes del if  7.0
220006718750 Valor variable coberturaCuota despues del if   0
220007719899 Valor variable coberturaCuota antes del if  2.0
220007719899 Valor variable coberturaCuota despues del if   0
220007768266 Valor variable coberturaCuota antes del if  2.0
220007768266 Valor variable coberturaCuota despues del if   0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema en tu código es que estás comparando en el if la variable *cuotaCobertura* cuando el resultado de la operación lo guardaste en la variable *coberturaCuota*.

Después, cuando imprimís dentro del if, el texto dice que es el valor de *coberturaCuota*, cuando en realidad imprimís *cuotaCobertura*.

No sé si tu intención es que fueran la misma variable. En ese caso, es importante recordar que deben tener el mismo nombre exacto, incluyendo mayúsculas porque [python es case sensitive](https://learnpython.com/blog/python-case-sensitive/#:%7E:text=Yes%2C%20Python%20Is%20a%20Case%2DSensitive%20Language&text=It%27s%20the%20differentiation%20between%20lower,sensitivity%20in%20Python%20is%20yes.), es decir, hace diferencia entre mayúsculas y minúsculas.

En caso de querer ser variables distintas, te recomiendo que pongas nombres descriptivos (que hablen sobre la variable y su objetivo o contenido) y distintos (para que no se mezclen con otras, como este caso).

Es bueno siempre tener presente [buenas prácticas para nombrar elementos](https://platzi.com/blog/buena-practica-codigo-nombrar-elementos/), así como las [convenciones sobre nombres](https://cosasdedevs.com/posts/convencion-nombres-python/). Si estás buscando alguna guía integral para hacer código más prolijo y legible, te recomiendo fuertemente aplicar [pep8](https://recursospython.com/pep8es.pdf).

Happy coding!